# Hyperbolic Coordinate Transformation in n-Sphere

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems, hyperbolic-functions

$x= r Cosh\theta$

$y= r Sinh\theta$

In 2D, the radius of hyperbolic circle is given by:

$\sqrt{x^2-y^2}$, which is r.

What about in 3D, 4D and higher dimensions.

In 3D, is the radius

$\sqrt{x^2-y^2-z^2}$?

Does one call them hyperbolic n-Sphere? How is the radius defined in these dimensions. In addition these coordinates doesn't seem equivalent. For Cosh only span positive space, while Sinh span both positive and negative space. How can we resolve this? What another hyperbolic coordinate system is good that resolves this problem? I am mainly interested in changing my coordinates x,y,z, etc. to hyperbolic coordinate system.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking x and y are coordinates so define a point  but what about r as in normal geometry radius and center are independent

Answer (score 1):

With $x=r\cosh\theta$ and $y=r\sinh\theta$ you get a hyperbola, or at least one branch of a hyperbola. Usually I'd interpret “hyperbolic circle” as “circle in hyperbolic geometry”, and unless you are dealing with some rare instances of the Beltrami-Klein model, the hyperbola you describe is not a circle of hyperbolic geometry.

The three-dimensional generalization of a hyperbola is called a  [*hyperboloid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid). For the $x^2-y^2-z^2=r^2$ you mention, you'd get the two-sheeted hyperboloid of revolution. That's the surface you get by rotating your hyperbola around the $x$ axis. You might parametrize one of its sheets (corresponding to one branch of the hyperbola) as

\begin{align*}
x&=r\cosh\theta\\
y&=r\sinh\theta\cos\varphi\\
z&=r\sinh\theta\sin\varphi
\end{align*}

But the one-sheeted hyperboloid $x^2-y^2+z^2=r^2$ is just as valid a generalization. It's what you get if you rotate your hyperbola around the $y$ axis. You might parametrize it as

\begin{align*}
x&=r\cosh\theta\cos\varphi\\
y&=r\sinh\theta\\
z&=r\cosh\theta\sin\varphi
\end{align*}

Comment: I believe the following coordinate transformation also works, equally well for the original case:
\begin{align}
x=rSinh\theta
\\
y=rCosh\theta Cos\phi
\\
z=rCosh\theta Sin\phi
\\
\end{align}
However, the Jacobian is negative, which is -$r^2Cosh\theta$. What does the negative Jacobian mean, does this sort of coordinate transformation change my results?

Comment: @t.jun: What you describe is again the one-sheeted hyperboloid. Comparing your parametrization with mine, you have $x$ and $y$ exchanged. You may see this as an orientation-reversing reflection in the plane $x=y$. Or you could see this as a different parametrization of a rotated version of the hyperboloid. BTW: you may want to look at my Math notation (using right click / Show Math As / TeX Commands) to learn about writing special functions and aligning equations, and/or read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/35416 about this.